# MySQL Service taking load on dedicated server

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have developed a web portal using php and mysql. This web portal contain details information of movies, actors, actresses, shortfilms, awards and lot more.. The database contain different masters and their related tables. I used id of masters as reference key and developed related mysql queries. I have included database connection on every page. Also it contain some functions to fetch data on pages. These functions are also fetching data after calculation of some values from database.

Everyday there are approximately 800 visitors to my website. Also some peoples are working in admin panel of this portal to manage and align data.
My current server is dedicated with 8GB RAM. When visitors get increase within a hour, my server get slow and sometimes totally hang. When I am checking server processes and service status, it shows that mysql service is taking too much load. I am unable to find exact problem in mysql or any other service. Also server logs are saying that "mysql process is on load" but I can't find exact problem. Server have WHM installed.

I have created indexes for columns which are normally including in where clause. What will be the problem in mysql service ?

**Points to note :**

1. I have created mysql connection in everypage. Is there any procedure to use same connection again and again ?
2. There are normally 2 columns in important table which contain indexes.
3. On average my portal have realtime 4-5 visits (In Google Analytics), at that time my server works very well but when visitors become 10-15 the server get slow or sometime hang.
4. Mysql service is the main issue told by server.
5. Database contain ~30 tables and 3-4 tables contain upto 2 lacks of rows.
6. I have writing queries in mysql.

Comment: Are you logging slow queries (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) and if so can you give an example.

Comment: Look with phpmyadmin at Server -> Status -> Processes. You can see all your queries with the current state